# Simple mechanics problem.

Tags: classical-mechanics

**Question**

A train is travelling West to East along a straight horizontal track. A child suspends
a pendulum from the roof of one of the carriages and notices that the pendulum is inclined at an
angle of 4◦
to the vertical. Calculate the acceleration of the train.

**Where I am at so far:**

Let the mass of the bob be m.

I don't know where to start, I don't even know if my diagram is correct.[image]

T is the tension in the string.

Comment: General relativity nitpick: What's "the vertical" if not exactly the direction a pendulum hangs?

Answer (score 1):

You know two things:

1. The vertical component of $T$ must equal the weight of the bob, since the bob is not accelerating vertically. So:

$T \cos(4^o)=mg$

2. The horizontal component of $T$ must be the force required to accelerate the bob horizontally at the same acceleration $a$ as the train (since the bob is stationary with respect to the train). So:

$T \sin(4^o)=ma$

You can eliminate $T$ and $m$ from these two equations and find an expression for $a$ in terms of $g$.

Comment: So does that mean my diagram is incorrect? The orange force that I drew is not meant to be there?

Comment: @CubbyKushi Yes. You can remove the orange arrow. Because the train is accelerating, the bob is *not* in equilibrium so you do not need a force to balance the horizontal component of $T$. It is the horizontal component of $T$ that is accelerating the bob so that it stays stationary w.r.t. the train.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the orange arrow is correct in a frame of reference attached to the train car. That frame of reference is a non-inertial frame and in that frame there is a so-called "fictitious" force that pulls on everything toward the left. But non-inertial frames are a more advanced topic and you don't need them for this problem. It is better to use an inertial frame, where we all understand the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Start with balance of forces projected:
$$
\begin{align}
ma = T \cos(90^\circ - 4^\circ)\\
mg = T \sin(90^\circ - 4^\circ)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the pendulum hangs at an angle of $\theta$. Then, we can equate horizontal and vertical forces to give $ma = T \sin \theta$ and $mg = T \cos \theta$. This yields $m = \frac{T}{a} \sin \theta$, so $\left ( \frac{T}{a} \sin \theta \right )g = T \cos \theta$, so $\boxed{a = g \tan \theta}$.